# PHPで変数に変数を代入した時に反映されない

Tags: php

変数animalsにHTMLの雛形を作っておいて、ホイールした時に雛形内の変数を反映させたいです。

構文

```
if(x == 0) {
    $animals = '<div>' . $lion . '</div>';
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
      $lion = 'ライオン';
      echo $animals;
    }
}
```

理想

```
<div>ライオン</div>
<div>ライオン</div>
<div>ライオン</div>
<div>ライオン</div>
```

結果

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

です

すみません、質問の説明の仕方がとても下手くそなんですが、実際は
$animalsには100行のHTML、PHP関数が書いてあります。
$lionにはwhile文の際に実行されるthe_content()によって$animalsの内容を反映することができます。

$animalsには100行を20回ほどループするので無駄が多くサイトM3-2XLARGEのスペックでも速度が重くなっています。

そこであらかじめテンプレートを作成しておいて、whileでループしても既に書き込まれたものを反映させるだけなので、この方法を探しています。

Comment: 本格的ならテンプレートエンジン（各種あります）を使うか、単純なら`'$lion'`としておいて置換する系(各種あります)の関数を使って置換する。あるいは、文字列を結合する関数を作っておいて`$lion`を引数として呼び出す。

Comment: 軽くするのが目的なので置換等したくないです。

Comment: ならば、関数呼び出しにするか、単に、`$animals = '<div>' . $lion . '</div>';` を`$lion = 'ライオン';` の後に置くようにすればいいかと思います。繰り返しを軽くするならそれをループの前に置くようにします。

Comment: 関数にしても反映されません。
ループ分に関数を置いても軽くなりません。

Comment: 構成される内容が変わらないならそれをループの前に出します。

Comment: 質問時はなるべく実行可能なコードを追加し、「軽くする」という曖昧な目的ではなくどのような問題が前提にあってどの程度軽くしなければならないのかを明確にすると、回答する側が答えやすくなります。

Comment: WordPressのwhile内にhtmlをループさせているのですが、あらかじめ雛形として用意しておいたhtmlをループ外に置いて、ループ時にthe_content()で作られる変数に雛形を入れたいです

Comment: 変数 `$lion` は `for` の中で書き換わるということですね？反映したい変数は `$lion` のみですか？実際にはもっとたくさんあるのでしょうか。 質問に書かれているコードが、曖昧さを助長している気がしますので 実際のものに近いコードを書けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$animal`を関数にして呼び出してしまえばOKです。

```
<?php

$animals = function ($animal) {
    $_animal = htmlspecialchars($animal, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return '<div>' . $_animal . '</div>';
};

for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $lion = 'ライオン';
    echo $animals($lion) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

追記: 関数がお嫌いなら、`printf`とか:

```
$div = '<div>%s</div>' . PHP_EOL;

for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $lion = 'ライオン';
    printf($div, $lion);
}
```

Comment: これでは関数がループされるので実行速度は遅くなってしまいます

Comment: 処理を関数として独立させることによる遅延は、全体から見ればごく僅かな物かと思います。その僅かな差を突き詰めるほど厳密なチューニングが必要なのであれば考慮すべきですが、目に見えて処理時間がかかっているのであれば、他にチューニングすべき場所を探してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: printf による変数展開の方法を追記しました。でもパフォーマンスチューニングと期待通り動くプログラムの作成は分けて考えたほうがいいよ？

Answer (score 1):

> `$animals = '<div>' . $lion . '</div>';`

右辺の `$lion` が評価され空文字になるため `$animals` の値は `<div></div>` になります。

質問のコードだけでは、何を求めているのか正直わかりませんが [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.eval.php) のような使い方を想定されてるように感じました。

evalは文字列をPHPコードとして解釈する関数です。変数を含める場合、意図しない操作が行われないことを必ず事前に確認する必要があります。[マニュアルにも記載があるように](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.eval.php)**一般にevalの使用は勧められません**。(この注記は元の回答者による物ではありません)

evalの例）

```
<?php
    $animals = '<div>$lion</div>';
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
      if ($i % 2 == 0)
        $lion = 'ライオン';
      else
        $lion = 'にゃんこ';
      eval('echo "' . $animals . '\n";');    // echo "<div>$lion</div>\n";
    }
?>
```

実行結果)

for の中で $lion の値が変わってもその都度、反映されるのが分かります。

```
$ php eval.php
<div>ライオン</div>
<div>にゃんこ</div>
<div>ライオン</div>
<div>にゃんこ</div>
<div>ライオン</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

コメントなどを見ると「処理が遅くなる」ということを危惧されているようですが、いずれの方法をとるにしても、最低限「雛形から変更したHTML文字列を作成する」処理は必要になります。
**存在しない文字列を出力することはできません。**

```
<div>ライオン</div>
<div>トラ</div>
<div>チーター</div>
```

このような出力をするには、

- 雛形に「ライオン」を適用した文字列
- 雛形に「トラ」を適用した文字列
- 雛形に「チーター」を適用した文字列

をそれぞれ作成しなくていはいけません。
これはテンプレートエンジンなどを利用する場合も同じです（表面上は見えなくても、内部で雛形に各動物の名前を適用した文字列を作成しているかと思います）

for文の中でそれぞれの動物の名前を適用した文字列を $animals に代入するのがオーソドックスな解決案かと思いますが、雛形自体が100行近くあるのでしたら、雛形を変動する部分の前後で分けてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
if(x == 0) {
    $animalArray = array('ライオン','トラ','チーター')
    $before = '<div>';
    $after = '</div>';

    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
      echo $before.$animalArray[$i].$after;
    }
}
```